# fscanf not reading in a file in Xcode in C

Tags: c, xcode, file, scanf

I'm trying to get my xcode to read in a file, but I keep getting a "build succeeded" and then (11db) as the output.

I have saved a file called "sudokode.in" to my desktop, and that's what I'm trying to open.

The file only has an integer, **19**, in it.

I just want to print out 19 to the screen.

I have never gotten my Xcode to read a file before, so I wouldn't know if I have to set it up, or what.  I have searched online and haven't found a real solution to this problem.

I appreciate the help.

```
int main() {

int num;

FILE* ifp = fopen("sudokode.in", "r");
fscanf(ifp, "%d", &num);

printf("%d", num);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should check whether `ifp` is `NULL` before trying to use it.

Comment: Check the result of `fopen`. I think your programme doesn't find the file because it's run from a different directory.

Comment: The executable isn't just going to randomly pull a file off of your desktop, it's going to search in the directory that the executable was launched from (in this case, a temp directory created by Xcode).

Comment: Okay, right Richard, that's what I was thinking.  I don't think my teacher went over this aspect; in his examples he just saves to the desktop and it works for him.  He uses a different compiler, though.  

So, the question is:  how do I change this temp directory?

Comment: @user2044189: Use absolute paths such as `/Users/John/Desktop/sudoke.in` instead. That saves you the hassle of copying the executable to the desktop every time Xcode compiles your code.

Comment: @user2044189 by copying the executable to your Desktop, and running it through the terminal there.

Answer (score 4):

The file probably doesn't exist. If that's the case, `ifp` will be `NULL`, so check for that:

```
int main() {

int num;

FILE* ifp = fopen("sudokode.in", "r");
if (ifp == NULL) {
    printf("Oops, this file doesn't exist!\n");
    return -1;
}
fscanf(ifp, "%d", &num);

printf("%d", num);

return 0;
}
```

Your program only works when you run it from the same directory that `sudoke.in` is stored in. You can use absolute paths (such as `/User/John/Desktop/sudoke.in`) instead.

Answer (score 0):

To set up your Working Directory to read and write to files in Xcode, go to Product --> Scheme --> Edit Scheme, and click that.

Then, click the check box by "Working Directory" and use the little gray file icon at the end of the field below to set the working directory.

I found a great explanation of how to do this for basic command-line projects in c on Xcode here:

https://www.meandmark.com/blog/2013/12/setting-the-current-working-directory-for-xcode-command-line-projects/